# Possible values of $b$ for $x^2 + bx + 6 = 0,$ for integer solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

The question is essentially in the title. The actual question is here(and also my working out) if there's any confusion in the title [http://m.imgur.com/a/lgNzt](https://m.imgur.com/a/lgNzt)

My method was to find the discriminant = 0 and then use trial and error since this question was multiple choice.

Is there a way of doing this properly, as in algebraically without trial and error?

Comment: I'm a little surprised that nobody mentioned [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas).

Answer (score 3):

Continuing your's work:
$\sqrt{b^2-24}=s\ \text{, s is integer}\implies b^2-s^2=24\implies (b-s)(b+s)=24$

Now, factor $24\begin{cases}24 &=1\cdot 24\\ 24 &=2\cdot 12\\ 24 &=3\cdot 8\\ 24 &=4\cdot 6\\ &\vdots\end{cases}$

Of which two products adds to an odd integer will not work for e.g. $(b-s)(b+s)=24=1\cdot 24$ here two product adds to $24+1=25$, odd,  hence kick it out. Similarly $24=8\cdot 3$ will be kicked out.  Leaving rest to verify it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

$pq=6$

We can have $(p,q)$ as  $(2,3),(1,6),(-2,-3),(-1,-6)$

So, $b$ can take $4$ values according to the sum of these pairs as $\pm5, \pm7$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2 + bx + 6 = 0\implies b=-\bigg(\frac{x^2+6}{x}\bigg)
= \bigg(-x - \frac{6}{x}\bigg)\\
 \implies x\in\{\pm1, \pm2, \pm3 \pm6 \}
 \quad\land\quad  b\in\{\pm5, \pm7\}$$

$$x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-24}}{2}\implies \sqrt{b^2-24}\in\mathbb{N}
\implies b\in \{ \cdots, \pm5, \pm7\, \cdots \}$$

Testing these results (and far beyond) confirms only one solution:
$\space (b,x)=(-7,1)$

Answer (score -1):

Let A and B be the roots. So A and B are integers.
(X-A)×(X-B)=X^2+bX+6

X^2+bX+6=X^2-(A+B)X+AB

So AB=6 . And they are integers. So possible value are

1×6 , -1×-6 , 2×3 , -2×-3.

b=-(A+B)

Putting above values , b=1+6 , -1+-6 , 2+3 ,-2,+-3
                                            7 , -7 , 5 , -5